# Delete errors from one Form Field in Angular's Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

Using Angular 8 I have a Reactive form:

```
form: FormGroup;

submitting: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {

  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
    income: [''],
    period: ['']
  })

}

onSubmit() {

  if (this.form.valid) {

    this.submitting = true;

    let model: Model = { 
      income: this.form.value.income,
      period: this.form.value.period
    }

    // Remaining code

}
```

When `form.value.income` has no value I would like to delete any errors associated with `form.value.period` and be able to submit the form.

How can I do this?

Comment: You should write your own custom validator in which you apply it on your desired form control (this case 'income') and you should make it dependent on another form control (this case 'period') with some condition that you meet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try somzthing lik this ?

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.form.valueChanges().subscribe(({ income }) => 
    if (income && income.length) {
      this.form.get('period').setErrors(null);
    }
  );
}
```

I didn't test it so you can go further.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I'll give it a shot.

A best practice would be to create a custom `Validator` (in your own separate file for separation) and then apply that `Validator` on the `formBuilder` `validator` global options.

Example:

**has-no-value.validator.ts**:

```
 import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export const hasNoValue = (controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) => { 
  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
      const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
      const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

      if (control.value === '') {
          matchingControl.setErrors(null);
      }
   }
}
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
    income: ['', [Validators.required]],
    period: ['', [Validators.required]]
  }, {
    validator: hasNoValue('income', 'period')
  });
}
```

A working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rd15bu